# java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, jpa, classcastexception

I have the following and I get the error

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

I have changed the `Object[]` to `String[]` because I faced the next error:

> java.lang.Object cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Any idea?

```
private Collection queryStatement(String SelectStatement) {

    int colcount = 0;
    int rowcount = 0;
    int rowcounter = 0;

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SelectStatement);

    List<String[]> resultList = (List<String[]>) query.getResultList();

    if (!resultList.equals(Collections.emptyList())) {
        rowcount = resultList.size();
    }

    if (rowcount > 0) {
        colcount = ((String[]) query.getResultList().get(0)).length;
    }

    rows = rowcount;
    cols = colcount;

    String[][] array = new String[rowcount][colcount];

    for (String[] obj : resultList) {
        String[] record = new String[colcount];
        for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter < colcount; colCounter++) {
            record[colCounter] = safeValue(obj[colCounter]+"");
        }

        array[ rowcounter++] = (String[]) record;
    }
    a.add(array);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What is your selectstatement? can you write query?

Comment: Naman SELECT PASSWD FROM AUDITORS WHERE USERNAME = '1114' But as you userstand the query is parameter

Comment: Why would that return a `List<String[]>` ? It looks like it's returning a `List<String>`, hence the error.

Comment: yes it will come List<String> because in query you have only one column PASSWD

Comment: Because the query is parameter (SelectStatement) is posssible to return List(String[])

Comment: Your code _assumes_ you'll get a `List<String[]>` instead of treating that as one of the possibilities.

Comment: That would make sense for `SELECT *`, but you're only selecting 1 attribute.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

This error occurs when you try to cast a `String` to an array of `String`.

**For example:**

```
List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
String[] values = (String[])list.get(0); -> throws the exception
```

For me you get this error because `query.getResultList()` returns a `List<String>` or `List<Object>` instead of `List<String[]>` such that when you try to cast a value as a `String[]` you get this exception.

---

According to the Javadoc [createNativeQuery(String](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-)) returns a result of type `Object[]` or a result of type `Object` if there is only one column in the select list.

#### Approach #1

One simple way to fix it, could be to rely on the **raw type** for the result (it is not the most elegant approach but the simplest one) then later you can check the type of the content of the list to cast it properly.

```
List result = query.getResultList();
```

Then to check the type you can proceed as next:

```
if (resultList.isEmpty() || resultList.get(0) instanceof Object[]) {
    // Several columns in the result
    List<Object[]> resultList = (List<Object[]>) result;
    // The rest of your current code here
} else {
    // Only one column in the result
    List<Object> resultList = (List<Object>) result;
    ...
}
```

#### Approach #2

A more elegant way could be to create an `Entity` class and use [`createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class entityClass)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) to create your query, this way it will automatically map your columns with the fields of your `Entity`

Here is how it could look like

```
private Collection<T> queryStatement(String SelectStatement, Class<T> resultType) {
    ...
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SelectStatement, resultType);
    List<T> resultList = (List<T>) query.getResultList();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nicolas Filotto you have right, but the Select query is parameter so on some time return List<String> if the SELECT have one column and List<String[][]> if have more than one. Any Idea how to fix  that?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, the second statement you make `This error occurs ...` is not strictly correct. I think you mean something like: "This error occurs when you try to cast a `String` object to an array of String objects `String[]`". If you use the word `List` as you have then you implicitly mean `java.util.List`

Comment: For approach #2, the POJO need to be an Entity class, or you will run into a MappingException. For native queries that don't return a mapped table or view, you'll need to go with approach #1

Answer (score 1):

At some point in your code you're trying to cast a String to String[]. Your stack trace will tell you where exactly.

Apart from that your code has plenty of other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
List<String> resultList = (List<String>) query.getResultList();
if (!resultList.equals(Collections.emptyList())) {
    rowcount = resultList.size();
}

if (rowcount > 0) {
     colcount = resultList.get(0).length;
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment at Nicolas Filotto you have right, but the Select query is parameter so on some time return List<String> if the SELECT have one column and List<String[]> if have more than one.

Comment: you are right @nicolas but here he has mentioned his query. I have already asked him that what is the query and it contains only one select column only.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
```

is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and so (potentailly) all objects in the code could be treaded as `Object`.

Try

```
ArrayList<String[][]> a = new ArrayList<>();
```